# Unable to send ether to contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am new to Solidity, I am trying to build a simple smart contract and explore solidity in the process. The following build can be compiled without putting a value but when i try to put some value in it it shows the following error.

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SimpleBank {
    string public name;
    address public owner;
    mapping (address => uint256) public funds;
    address[] public funders;
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256){
        return owner.balance;
    }
    function getAddress() public view returns(address){
        return owner;
    }
    function RecieveMoney() public payable{
        funds[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked for me.

[image]

Are you specifying the balance ammount to send before sending the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You probably put in an amount in the payable field that was greater than the current balance of your account. There are no errors in the code.